# Referencing listobject tables in different sheets

Tags: excel, vba

Here is the basic methodology that I assumed would work to print data into a table in a different sheet.

```
Dim ws as Worksheet

Set ws = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Cost")

Dim tb as ListObject

set tb = ws.Listobjects("Table8")

Debug.Print tb.DataBodyRange(1, 1).Value
```

I expect this to return the value in the first cell of the table. My real intention is to enter values into this table but I get the same error when I run this debug.print as I do when I try to feed values.

"Object variable or With block variable not set" on running the last line of this example.
What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the help

Comment: @QHarr Oh that's unfortunate.
Do you know a workaround because I want the table to be empty since I'm the one feeding values into it.

Comment: You will this with an empty table (there is a difference between empty table with headers versus a table with headers and a single blank row).

Comment: You can first test if `If Not tb.DataBodyRange Is Nothing` You can also still work off the parent object e.g. `tb.InsertRowRange.Cells(1, 1) = "abc"`

Comment: Thank you. i understand the problem now. Your solution with adding values in the cell also helped.